# How to make a GET request to the Eclipse bugzilla API?

Tags: python, eclipse, rest, request, bugzilla

I've been working with the mozilla version of bugzilla, to which i make get requests using the follow url: `https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug?limit=10&status=NEW&type=defect`.

I wanted to do similiar requests but this time to the Eclipse project, which I know also uses bugzilla (just dont know the version, or if that is even relevant) `https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/`, however I can't seem to find the documentation that shows me how to get lists of bugs.

E.g: I do `https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/rest/bug?id=1815490` to get a specific bug in the mozilla project, and it works. When I do `https://bugs.eclipse.org/rest/bug?id=251041`, I get a 404, the same as with other similar URLs. Any ideas?

Comment: Actually a lot of Eclipse projects have switched to Github now.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's it, since we can still access/search/file bugs through https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/ and I want to search all Eclipse bugs, not project specific

Comment: Look at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi and you will see that several projects no longer use bugzilla for new bug reports.

Comment: Yes I can see that, but thats not relevant for me since I'm working on bug classification ML. I just wanted some bugs from the eclipse page for training, since i already have most available from the Mozilla page. I dont mind if the bugs are old or not. I'd just rather work with this API since I've already built all the algorithm, just the URL is missing :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The base URL is **`https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs`**, not `https://bugs.eclipse.org`, e.g. [`https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/rest/bug?id=251041`](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/rest/bug?id=251041)

Please be aware that Eclipse Bugzilla is deprecated and many Eclipse projects have migrated to GitHub and some to https://gitlab.eclipse.org/.